# What's the difference between an "option" and a "switch?"

Tags: command-line

When running commands on Windows or Linux, it seems like the terms option or switch are used interchangeably. Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

If you do `dir /?`  or `copy /?` in e.g. windows 7,  you see use of the term switch. e.g. copy /? describes "The switch /Y".

windows uses the term switch for /X (or /XY or /X:Y), linux uses option and -x or --blah. There are one or two windows commands that can use hiphen/dash eg ping,  and there, when it's hiphen, windows calls it an option as you see from `ping -?`

looking at current microsoft documentation online whether for [**ping**](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true) or for [**dir**](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true) they refer to parameters, so each of those items be it /b for dir, or -n for ping, would be termed a parameter.